# Progressive cart item fee based on state and on product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, state, fee

Recently I tryied to use 2 sniped codes in one for this Woocommerce project where I need to set a fee for a specific product category (term ID: 19) and and a specific country state (Florida 'FL')

Additionally I should need to multiply this fee rate by the items from this product category (19).

This is my actual code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge'); 
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
    $category_ID = '19'; 

    global $woocommerce;


    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $state  = array('FL');


    foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $key => $values ) {
    // Get the terms, i.e. category list using the ID of the product

    $terms = get_the_terms( $values['product_id'], 'product_cat' );
    // Because a product can have multiple categories, we need to iterate through the list of the products category for a match
    foreach ($terms as $term) 
    {
        // 19 is the ID of the category for which we want to remove the payment gateway
        if($term->term_id == $category_ID){
    $surcharge  = 1;

    if ( in_array( WC()->customer->shipping_state, $state && ) ) {
        $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'State Tire Fee', $surcharge, true, '' );
    }
}
```

How can I set a progressive fee based on items from a specific category and customers from a specific state?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's your question ?

Comment: when i try to put this in my template of wordpress i got an error... the site just dont work... so can you help me to detect the possible error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes and your code is a bit outdated... 
The code below will set a progressive fee based on cart item quantity from a specific product category and for a specific state only.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'wc_custom_surcharge', 20, 1 );
function wc_custom_surcharge( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return; // Exit

    ## Your Settings (below) ##

    $categories      = array(19);
    $targeted_states = array('FL');
    $base_rate       = 1;

    $user_state = WC()->customer->get_shipping_state();
    $user_state = empty($user_state) ? WC()->customer->get_billing_state() : $user_state;
    $surcharge  = 0; // Initializing

    // If user is not from florida we exit
    if ( ! in_array( $user_state, $targeted_states ) )
        return; // Exit

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] )  ){
            // calculating fee based on the defined rate and on item quatinty
            $surcharge += $cart_item['quantity'] * $base_rate;
        }
    }

    // Applying the surcharge
    if ( $surcharge > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( __("State Tire Fee", "woocommerce"), $surcharge, true );
    }
}
```

Code goes in `function.php` file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much! work perfectly! i using this code and i hope help someone else...! have a great day Mr Loic