# How can I exclude Taxes From a custom COD Surcharge in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tax, fee

I'm wondering how can I exclude the Cash on Delivery Surcharge from Taxes?

I have used *[Add fee for Cash on delivery payment method (cod) in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382278/add-fee-for-cash-on-delivery-payment-method-cod-in-woocommerce/38384483#38384483)* code to add the COD Surcharge

I want to have this charge excluded from VAT & no VAT/TAX shall be applied to it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have that COD surcharge not taxable, you will replace in the code:

```
$cart->add_fee( 'Handling', $fee, true );
```

by:

```
$cart->add_fee( 'Handling', $fee, false );
```

> As the third argument in `WC_Cart` `add_fee()` method is "taxable" (`true` or `false`)

---

Or if you have set a "Zero Rate" on your tax settings, you can also use instead:

```
$cart->add_fee( 'Handling', $fee, true, 'zero-rate' );
```

> As the fourth argument in `WC_Cart` `add_fee()` method is "tax class"

See: [Set a Zero tax rate on a cart fee in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622377/set-a-zero-tax-rate-on-a-cart-fee-in-woocommerce/53643272#53643272)